# Ionic 4: Initialize component when back button is called

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have been using the below code to go back to the previous page:

```
<ion-toolbar color="primary">
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
```

I have a requirement where I need to re-render the previous component when the back is clicked.

I have tried lifecycle hooks like ngOnInit(), ngAfterViewInit() etc. but none of them is called when the back button is called.

Please let me know a possible way to handle this requirement.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `ionViewWillEnter` hook of Ionic instead of using angular lifecycle hook `ngOnInit()`

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   // your code to initialize
}
```

Here are other lifecycle hooks of Ionic

```
constructor --> ionViewDidLoad --> ionViewWillEnter --> ionViewDidEnter --> ionViewWillLeave --> ionViewDidLeave --> ionViewWillUnload.
```

Comment: IonViewWillEnter is invoked even when page is loaded for the first time. I need hook which got triggered only and only when back button is clicked?

Comment: life cycle hooks are never linked to any component triggering, back-button is an ionic component.

Answer (score -1):

You may call function on back button click like this,

```
// .ts file

gotoPreviousPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push('PreviousPage');
  }
```